# Using Okta and Blazor, in c#, LocalRedirect() gets stuck in a loop with error "Too Many Requests"

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, okta

I have tried to implement Okta login in my app. I'm running a test app to figure it out before I edit the real app. I load the url and it authenticates through Okta as it should. Then it does to a page saying "Loading..." for a few seconds and then gives an error:
[image]

The LocalRedirect(redirectUri) should redirect to "/". Instead it loops back into the Login function again.

LoginController.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestOktaLogin.Controllers {
    public class LoginController : Controller {
        [HttpGet("Login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromQuery] string returnUrl) {
            var redirectUri = returnUrl is null ? "/" : "/" + returnUrl;

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                return LocalRedirect(redirectUri); //It does not return. It just reloads the function.
            }

            return Challenge();
        }

        // This is the method the Logout button should get to when clicked.
        [HttpGet("Logout")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Logout([FromQuery] string returnUrl) {
            var redirectUri = returnUrl is null ? Url.Content("~/") : "/" + returnUrl;

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
            }

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();

            return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

RedirectToLogin.razor.cs:

````
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace TestOktaLogin.Components {
    public partial class RedirectToLogin : ComponentBase {
        [Inject] public NavigationManager Navigation { get; set; }

        protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
            var returnUrl = Navigation.ToBaseRelativePath(Navigation.Uri);

            Navigation.NavigateTo($"Login?returnUrl={returnUrl}", true);
        }
    }
}```




Home.razor, which is the default to "/":
````

@page "/"

@attribute [Authorize]

Home

## Hello, world!

Welcome to your new app.```

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using TestOktaLogin.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddMvc();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(authOptions => {
    authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddOpenIdConnect(oidcOptions => {
    oidcOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Okta:ClientId"];
    oidcOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Okta:ClientSecret"];
    oidcOptions.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
    oidcOptions.Authority = builder.Configuration["Okta:Issuer"];
    oidcOptions.ResponseType = "code";
    oidcOptions.SaveTokens = true;
    oidcOptions.Scope.Add("openid");
    oidcOptions.Scope.Add("profile");
    oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    oidcOptions.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
}).AddCookie();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();
```

Edit:
Here is my Routes.razor

```
@using TestOktaLogin.Components.Layout

<CascadingValue Name="AccessToken" Value="AccessToken">
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
        <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
            <Found Context="routeData">
                <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData=@routeData DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <NotAuthorized>
                        <RedirectToLogin /> @* Would this cause the problem? *@
                    </NotAuthorized>
                    <Authorizing>
                        Authorizing...
                    </Authorizing>
                </AuthorizeRouteView>
            </Found>
            <NotFound>
                <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
                <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                    <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
                </LayoutView>
            </NotFound>
        </Router>
    </CascadingAuthenticationState>

</CascadingValue>

@code{
    [Parameter] public string AccessToken { get; set; }
}
```

Here is MainLayout.razor

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div>
    <LoginDisplay/>
</div>

@Body

<div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
</div>
```

If there is any additional code I need to upload, let me know. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Did you check if _returnUrl_ is a blank string? (Not null but empty)

Comment: Did you mean returnUri in the LoginController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following loop:

```
User -> Login -> Okta -> LoginController -> LocalRedirect -> Home (Authorized)
  ^                                                                  |
  |__________________________________________________________________|
```

That loop occurs because after the `LocalRedirect`, the user is being redirected back to the login process instead of the home page.

In the `Login` action, you are checking if the user is authenticated and then performing a `LocalRedirect`.
The `Challenge` method is correctly placed to initiate the authentication process, when the user is not authenticated.

The loop does not originate from the `Challenge` itself, but may occur if after the user is authenticated: they are redirected back to a route that requires authentication and the [`Authorize` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0#selecting-the-scheme-with-the-authorize-attribute) redirects them back to the login page because it does not recognize the user as authenticated.

See also "[Overview of ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)"

The specific part in your `LoginController` where the `Challenge` is issued:

```cs
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
    return LocalRedirect(redirectUri); // If authenticated, redirect to the return URL or home
} else {
    return Challenge(); // If not authenticated, initiate the authentication process
}
```

The potential issue might be with the `LocalRedirect(redirectUri)` line: if the `redirectUri` is somehow misconfigured and redirects back to a page that ends up redirecting to `/Login` again (like the `RedirectToLogin` component might do), this would create a loop. That loop would continue until the browser stops it due to too many redirects, resulting in the "`Too Many Requests`" error you are seeing.

Also, the middleware in `Program.cs` might be misconfigured, not properly maintaining the authentication state or using an incorrect `Authorize` attribute usage in `Home.razor`.

To debug this issue:

- make sure `redirectUri` is a valid and accessible route after authentication.
- confirm that the `Home` page recognizes the authentication state and does not redirect back to the `Login` page.
- verify that the authentication middleware in `Program.cs` is correctly configured to handle the auth state after login.
- use logging to trace the redirect flow to see exactly where the redirection loop is occurring.

If these checks are all correct, the loop should be broken, and the user should be correctly redirected to the home page after authentication.

---

Make sure your `Login` action is not being called again after a successful authentication.
That should be done by adjusting the [`redirectUri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationproperties.redirecturi?view=aspnetcore-7.0) logic and making sure the `Challenge` only occurs when necessary.

Your `LoginController` would then be:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace TestOktaLogin.Controllers {
    public class LoginController : Controller {
        [HttpGet("Login")]
        public IActionResult Login([FromQuery] string returnUrl) {
            // Make sure returnUrl is not causing a loop back to this action
            var redirectUri = Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)
                ? returnUrl
                : "/";

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                // Redirect to the original requested resource or home if authenticated
                return LocalRedirect(redirectUri);
            }

            // Only issue a challenge if the user is not authenticated
            return Challenge();
        }

        // Rest of your code
    }
}
```

You now have a check to make sure that `returnUrl` is local and not `null` or empty to prevent redirection to an unauthorized route which might cause the loop.

For the `RedirectToLogin` component, make sure it is only being used in cases where the user is not authenticated, otherwise, it could also contribute to the loop.

You will also want to make sure your OpenID Connect configuration and the `Authorize` attribute usage in `Home.razor` are correctly set up to prevent unauthorized access, which could cause a redirect back to the login process.

---

The [OP Timothy Waters](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8257274/timothy-waters) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432354/using-okta-and-blazor-in-c-localredirect-gets-stuck-in-a-loop-with-error-t/77452830#comment136548249_77452830):

> The fix was your change to `LoginController.cs` and a couple other things.
>
> 1. I removed `LoginDisplay` from everything especially `<div> <LoginDisplay/> </div>` from `MainLayout.razor`.
> 2. I added `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` to `Routes.razor`.
>
> Worked after that.

True: By removing `LoginDisplay` from your components, you may have eliminated any conflicting authentication logic that might have been causing the redirection loop.
And adding `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization` allows your Blazor components to access the necessary authentication functionality, making sure the authentication state is correctly recognized.

These changes, along with the modifications made to `LoginController.cs` as mentioned above, helped in resolving the issue.

Comment: I have added my Routs.razor above. There is a RedirectToLogin object in there. Would that cause the loop? If so, how would I fix that?

Comment: Ok. The fix was your change to LoginController.cs and a couple other things. 1. I removed LoginDisplay from everything especially  ` <div>
    <LoginDisplay/>
</div> ` from MainLayout.razor. 2. I added  ` @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization
 ` to Routes.razor. Worked after that. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: @TimothyWaters Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.